# Aborted(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory[...])

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, vercel, tesseract.js

I'm getting this issue after deploying my code on vercel;it was working completely fine in my local environment. I'm not able find solution for this problem anywhere.

> Aborted(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.wasm')
> 2023-01-04T06:54:46.648Z  7c70e537-4119-465d-924c-f90026df64fc    ERROR   Uncaught
> Exception     {"errorType":"RuntimeError","errorMessage":"Aborted(Error:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.wasm').
> Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.","stack":["RuntimeError:
> Aborted(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.wasm').
> Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.","    at n
> (/var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.js:18:375)","
> at Ua
> (/var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.js:19:317)","
> at
> /var/task/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core-simd.js:20:394"]}
> Unknown application error occurred Runtime .Unknown

I used `tesseract.js` package and it was working good on my local environment, but not on Vercel production server

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, I think that the problem is that you are importing createWorker

```
import { createWorker } from "tesseract.js";
```

try to change the import to

```
import Tesseract from "tesseract.js";
```

and then use it like

```
Tesseract.createWorker();
//image- path of image you want to use, lang- language you want to use
Tesseract.recognize(image, "lang");
```

Comment: Still after changing the (creatWorker to Tesseract) the error is still persist. Domagoj

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and everything works, I started a new Next.js project with

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

then added tesseract.js to the project

```
npm install tesseract.js
```

this is what the simple index.js file looks like

```
import Tesseract from "tesseract.js";

Tesseract.createWorker({
  logger: (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  },
});
let file = [];

const recognize = async () => {
  const {
    data: { text },
  } = await Tesseract.recognize(file, "eng");
  console.log(text);
};

const onFileChange = (event) => {
  const input = event.target.files;
  file = input[0];
  console.log(file);
  recognize();
};

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => onFileChange(e)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I tested both on local environment and vercel production server and all should work.
Hope it helps

Comment: Domagoj Vrkić I tried your approach but it still fails and I think the problem with wasm file is not bundeled in at build time on vercel. And I still getting the same error. Thank for the suggestion